# Execution of mysql query using python mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

Consider the code below

```
Table="USER"
fields="("+'username'+")"
values=('vishnu',)
dbcon = MySQLdb.connect(...)
insert_query="insert into %s%s values%%s"%(Table,fields)

cursor=dbcon.cursor()
cursor.execute(insert_query,(values,))
cursor.close()
dbcon.commit()
```

This code work differently for two system. In my laptop its working well but in my desktop it shows MYSQL syntax error.

I can't resolve this issue? What will be the reason, i am using same version of python2.7.

Comment: how do you execute the python code in both ?

Comment: did you check MySQL version?

Comment: @SaranyaSridharan What you mean by how? I put this code in a .py file just run it

Comment: Sometimes it gives different result when you run from eclipse or through console. Okay

Comment: @ManojJadhav I didn't check that, If there is difference, will there chance to show error like this?

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: @ManojJadhav mysql version is same 14.14 but there is a difference in distribution. In laptop it is 5.5.54 but in my desktop it is 5.5.58. May this will be the reason?

Comment: @mhawke I will do that. Now i havn't access to my desktop, i am far away from it.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the difference in MySQLdb versions. Try with same version of MySQLdb.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is with MySQLdb version